# Invalid type for argument 1 to gimp-image-crop when trying to batch crop in GIMP Batch Mode

Tags: linux, bash, procedure, gimp

I have some 1080x1920 png files and I want to crop them into 1080x1728 with offset-y 65, so I tried and it returns this:

`gimp -i -b '(gimp-image-crop "*.png" 1080 1728 0 65)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'`

```
$ ll
total 1796
drwxrwxr-x 2 cat cat   4096 Jul 25 15:06 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 cat cat   4096 Jul 25 14:37 ../
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat 278356 Jul  9 10:56 1.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat 278356 Jul  9 10:56 Screenshot_20210709-105437.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat  58088 Jul  9 10:56 Screenshot_20210709-105445.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat 108385 Jul  9 14:54 Screenshot_20210709-145331.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat 130486 Jul  9 22:18 Screenshot_20210709-221631.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat 133602 Jul  9 22:20 Screenshot_20210709-221834.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat 153976 Jul  9 22:22 Screenshot_20210709-222035.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat 149365 Jul  9 22:23 Screenshot_20210709-222039.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat 124369 Jul 11 17:01 Screenshot_20210711-165959.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat 138719 Jul 24 23:06 Screenshot_20210724-230338.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat  88272 Jul 24 23:06 Screenshot_20210724-230346.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat 104779 Jul 24 23:06 Screenshot_20210724-230356.png*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cat cat  63867 Jul 24 23:05 Screenshot_20210724-230408.png*

$ gimp -i -b '(gimp-image-crop "*.png" 1080 1728 0 65)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)' 
batch command experienced an execution error:
Error: Invalid type for argument 1 to gimp-image-crop 

$
```

It always returns `Invalid type for argument 1 to gimp-image-crop`.

I check in Procedure Browser in GIMP and it tells:

[image]

The argument 1 is "THE IMAGE". I also tried "1.png" and ".+png" but it always returns the same error: `Error: Invalid type for argument 1 to gimp-image-crop`

I don't understand which part I do wrong.

My OS is Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon and GIMP version is 2.10.18.

Please help.

Comment: Seems like the `IMAGE` parameter has to be an ID of an already opened image (see [API](https://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/libgimp/libgimp-gimpimage.html#gimp-image-crop), where it is called `image_ID`), not a filename. You probably have to export the modified images too, otherwise you would loose all the changes. By the way: With imagemagick this would be very simple: `mogrify -resize 1080x1728+0+65 *.png`.

Comment: Yeah I'm using imagemagick instead now.
The document of GIMP Batch Mode <https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/> seems about wrong.

Comment: I cannot spot an error in your linked page. There are examples like `gimp -i -b '(simple-unsharp-mask "foo.png" 5.0 0.5 0)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'`, but there `simple-unsharp-mask` is a custom script which executes commands like `(gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE filename filename)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `image` argument of `gimp-image-crop` is the handle of a loaded image in Gimp, not an image file. So you have to `gimp-file-load` the image (this gives you a handle), apply your operations, and then `gimp-file-save`. Note that saving an image to a "flat" format (JPG, PNG...) is actually saving a **layer**, so if your image is more than one layer you may have to first create a layer to save using `gimp-layer-new-from-visible`.

This said, agreed that in most cases it is faster to use ImageMagick.